# Xaml Listview ItemTapped Binding MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a Listview in Xaml and I need to bind ItemTapped event to my ModelView using MVVM.

My ListView looks like.

```
<ListView x:Name="list"
    ItemsSource="{Binding employeeList}" 
    ItemTapped= {Binding selectedItem} >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
   <ViewCell>
   <ViewCell.View>


   </ViewCell.View>
   </ViewCell>
   </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
   </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

`ItemTapped` is an event which, in MVVM, normally corresponds to an `ICommand`*. If you meant to bind to a normal data property, judging from the attempted binding statement in your XAML snippet, then it would make more sense to do bind `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` property instead :

```
<ListView x:Name="list"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    .....
</ListView>
```

If there is data related action that need to be taken upon `ItemTapped` event occur, it might instead be implemented on `SelectedItem` property changed which triggered via binding (as in the XAML binding above) :

```cs
private ItemModel _selectedItem;
public ItemModel SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if(_selectedItem != value)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

            //this can be placed before or after propertychanged notification raised, 
            //depending on the situation
            DoSomeDataOperation();
        }
    }
}
```

*) Xamarin Blog : [Turn Events into Commands with Behaviors](https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/)